# regarding port forwarding

Tags: networking, internet

I have designed a chat application using servlets and jsp. I do not like it to host on any web hosting sites. I wanna make my computer only as server and wanna make it accessible to the users of different network. Can anybody explain me how can this be achieved. I will be really thankful. I was said that use port forwarding how can this be solved using port forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think you'd be well served by using [Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/).  I believe you'll need to use the [Web Proxy](http://unite.opera.com/application/272/) application.

You'll need to sign up for a free opera account, and then they'll give you a URL (something like yourcomputer.yourusername.opera.com, IIRC) that people can access your site from, whenever your computer is up and running.  Using the Web Proxy will allow you to run whatever sort of web application you like.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is get a static IP address from your ISP and connect your computer directly to the Internet connection, configured with this IP. Then just give our your IP address and port number for your application. Of course that is a security risk so you will probably need to put a firewall in place to block all ports except the ones used by your application. If you are doing this on the cheap and cannot get a static IP but only have a dynamic IP, you will need to sign up with one of the dynamic DNS providers and use the host name they give you instead of the IP address. If your ISP firewalls the Internet connection for you, you will have to talk to them about opening up the port for your application. The directions for opening up a port vary by firewall model. If you need further help with a specific firewall, update your question with the specific model.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have the server already configured and working in your machine then the only thing you should do is opening and forwarding the port on your router... The problem here is that every router has a different web interface, so introducing http://portforward.com/ . Here you can find how to configure port forward in several routers. Configuring port forward is 3 things: public port, private address, private port. For instance if you want that the public service be in the 8080 port and your private address is 192.168.0.50 and your private port 80, then you would have to configure:

8080 > 192.168.0.50:80

Another thing you'll have to be aware is regarding the public IP address. Most of the times your ISP will give you a dynamic IP, so from time to time it will change; the solution for this problem are services like no-ip.org or dynDNS. They are daemons that works on most of Operating Systems, and you can have a DNS which will change where is pointing to when your IP address changes. Also some times your router will let you configure this.